# Difference in compiler design for OOP languages

Tags: oop, compiler-construction

I'm doing research on how the design of a compiler for an OOP language differs from traditional imperative languages. I'd just like some topics to send me on my way, and if you wish, you can explain them.

For eg. I found that the type table is built differently.

Comment: which reduces the likelihood of other people answering for reputation? Its a programming problem...

Comment: @Shawn Mclean, No I just suggested community wiki since this question doesn't seem to have a clear-cut answer.  And from the FAQ `Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered.`  It just seemed that your question might subjective and require extended discussion, so marking it as a Wiki might be nicer.  Good luck though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the "compiler design" can be explored, I think the more fundamental question of "language design" needs to be addressed.

Should the language be statically typed? Dynamically typed? Early/late bound or a combination? Supporting generics? Is inference a goal? Should types be closed or open? How should sub-typing work? (Should implicit sub-typing be allowed at all?) Covariance? Contravariance? Single-inheritance? MI? SI with Traits? Explicit memberwise-selection? Prototypal (That is, should there even be a notion of "class" and "instance"?) Should types in nominative or based off of member signatures? Single-dispatch or multiple-dispatch? Are members invoked as first-class citizens or message-passing? Are types the same as classes? Is there a distinction between "value" and "reference" types? Etc, etc, etc... and this is just the tip of a very large iceberg.